# Loop all Tables and Exec stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have dozens of tables (MS SQL) and what to implement on all a trigger for audit.  There would be a lots of EXEC calls. How to loop trough all of the tables and exec the stored proc?

```
EXEC [dbo].[_create_audit_trigger]  @TableName = N'City'
```

Comment: use `while loop`, `cursor`, your choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG( 
                         CAST(CONCAT('EXEC [dbo].[_create_audit_trigger]  @TableName = N''', 
                                QUOTENAME(S.Name), 
                                '.', 
                                QUOTENAME(T.Name), 
                                N''''
                               ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
                        ';')
FROM Sys.Tables T
JOIN Sys.Schemas S ON T.Schema_Id = S.Schema_Id;

SELECT @SQL; -- EXEC
-- EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ad3db78275a34c8525c2bb248ec0f6c)

Comment: This also just created the script and did not execute it.

Comment: @Vlado There is a comment there, just change `SELECT @SQL;` with `EXEC (@SQL);`

Comment: I did and got an error: The name - 'EXEC [dbo].[_create_audit_trigger]  @TableName = N'AppSetting'...... EXEC [dbo].[_c' is not a valid identifier. - it truncated the SQL

Comment: Do you have a table name like `[C'ity]`? What does `SELECT @SQL;` returns?

Comment: No apostrophes in names. The error is too long to put in here. It ends with EXEC [dbo].[_c' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: [It works just fine for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9f0a52533df5fb4e248575e54a38f961) @Vlado If you 've a lot of tables then you can just cast as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

Comment: the 'sp_executesql' did the magic. It works now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'EXEC [dbo].[_create_audit_trigger]  @TableName = N''' + QUOTENAME(schemas.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(tables.name) + N''''
FROM sys.tables
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ON tables.schema_id = schemas.schema_id
```

Comment: That works just fine to create a script to copy and run. Is there a way to also automatically execute it?

Comment: It's possible. The next one answer can do it.